Three.js ExtrudeGeometry CatmullRomCurve3 not closing
I am struggling with this one problem with my extruded geometry, that the two ends of the rails for the railroad are not at the same rotation and therefore are not closing properly:

Here is what my curve data looks like:
{
    "curve": {
      "metadata": {
        "version": 4.6,
        "type": "Curve",
        "generator": "Curve.toJSON"
      },
      "arcLengthDivisions": 200,
      "type": "CatmullRomCurve3",
      "points": [
        [
          1.9841800928115845,
          0.5334839820861816,
          1.0582462549209595
        ],
        [
          1.6753532886505127,
          0.5593564510345459,
          1.0589643716812134
        ],
        [
          1.4491666555404663,
          0.697923481464386,
          1.0587162971496582
        ],
        [
          1.3111166954040527,
          0.9186244010925293,
          1.0582331418991089
        ],
        [
          1.2667001485824585,
          1.1908986568450928,
          1.0582462549209595
        ],
        [
          1.1812900304794312,
          1.5252690315246582,
          1.0673372745513916
        ],
        [
          0.9781750440597534,
          1.7057092189788818,
          1.0242031812667847
        ],
        [
          0.7563002109527588,
          1.8089666366577148,
          0.8255313634872437
        ],
        [
          0.6146100759506226,
          1.9117887020111084,
          0.368009090423584
        ],
        [
          0.5726678371429443,
          1.9956049919128418,
          0.18548542261123657
        ],
        [
          0.4700773060321808,
          2.130831718444824,
          0.022279858589172363
        ],
        [
          0.2809561789035797,
          2.2566030025482178,
          -0.09508982300758362
        ],
        [
          -0.020577847957611084,
          2.3120527267456055,
          -0.14010587334632874
        ],
        [
          -0.3296802341938019,
          2.281888723373413,
          -0.09030210971832275
        ],
        [
          -0.5734552145004272,
          2.1982598304748535,
          0.063102126121521
        ],
        [
          -0.7143107652664185,
          2.0714614391326904,
          0.32609623670578003
        ],
        [
          -0.714654803276062,
          1.9117887020111084,
          0.704669713973999
        ],
        [
          -0.6603711843490601,
          1.6230847835540771,
          1.0399469137191772
        ],
        [
          -0.7036638259887695,
          1.2259819507598877,
          1.1522256135940552
        ],
        [
          -0.8844012022018433,
          0.8598360419273376,
          1.1333403587341309
        ],
        [
          -1.2424516677856445,
          0.6640021800994873,
          1.07512629032135
        ],
        [
          -1.5709213018417358,
          0.710712730884552,
          0.9744400978088379
        ],
        [
          -1.7952327728271484,
          0.9225581288337708,
          0.7847572565078735
        ],
        [
          -1.918294906616211,
          1.2473043203353882,
          0.5570305585861206
        ],
        [
          -1.9430160522460938,
          1.632717251777649,
          0.34221315383911133
        ],
        [
          -1.9179303646087646,
          1.7906527519226074,
          0.2413727045059204
        ],
        [
          -1.8539397716522217,
          1.9498507976531982,
          0.08201402425765991
        ],
        [
          -1.7422277927398682,
          2.074662685394287,
          -0.1307205855846405
        ],
        [
          -1.5739785432815552,
          2.12943959236145,
          -0.39168858528137207
        ],
        [
          -1.4084653854370117,
          2.101039409637451,
          -0.6227225065231323
        ],
        [
          -1.2622238397598267,
          2.018277645111084,
          -0.7576898336410522
        ],
        [
          -1.062330961227417,
          1.9084441661834717,
          -0.8094995021820068
        ],
        [
          -0.7358642816543579,
          1.7988282442092896,
          -0.791060745716095
        ],
        [
          -0.3141660988330841,
          1.636258602142334,
          -0.7310407757759094
        ],
        [
          -0.11715522408485413,
          1.4371027946472168,
          -0.6912686824798584
        ],
        [
          0.0005134642124176025,
          1.210427165031433,
          -0.674283504486084
        ],
        [
          0.18418511748313904,
          0.9652981162071228,
          -0.6826245188713074
        ],
        [
          0.541795551776886,
          0.7710164189338684,
          -0.713899552822113
        ],
        [
          0.8791866898536682,
          0.8175182938575745,
          -0.7456703782081604
        ],
        [
          1.1301640272140503,
          1.0657851696014404,
          -0.7703192234039307
        ],
        [
          1.2285329103469849,
          1.4767986536026,
          -0.7802283763885498
        ],
        [
          1.270639419555664,
          1.7391345500946045,
          -0.7550599575042725
        ],
        [
          1.4038491249084473,
          1.9311418533325195,
          -0.6573927402496338
        ],
        [
          1.638497233390808,
          2.011077642440796,
          -0.45398378372192383
        ],
        [
          1.984919548034668,
          1.9371986389160156,
          -0.11159008741378784
        ],
        [
          2.377054452896118,
          1.6190400123596191,
          0.35915905237197876
        ],
        [
          2.5386343002319336,
          1.1714740991592407,
          0.7284424304962158
        ],
        [
          2.4231719970703125,
          0.7558417916297913,
          0.9701688289642334
        ]
      ],
      "closed": true,
      "curveType": "centripetal",
      "tension": 0.5
    },
    "mesh": {
      "metadata": {
        "version": 4.6,
        "type": "Object",
        "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
      },
      "geometries": [
        {
          "uuid": "334a7738-6879-4941-9bbf-a7d762a1ae27",
          "type": "TubeGeometry",
          "path": {
            "metadata": {
              "version": 4.6,
              "type": "Curve",
              "generator": "Curve.toJSON"
            },
            "arcLengthDivisions": 200,
            "type": "CatmullRomCurve3",
            "points": [
              [
                1.9841800928115845,
                0.5334839820861816,
                1.0582462549209595
              ],
              [
                1.6753532886505127,
                0.5593564510345459,
                1.0589643716812134
              ],
              [
                1.4491666555404663,
                0.697923481464386,
                1.0587162971496582
              ],
              [
                1.3111166954040527,
                0.9186244010925293,
                1.0582331418991089
              ],
              [
                1.2667001485824585,
                1.1908986568450928,
                1.0582462549209595
              ],
              [
                1.1812900304794312,
                1.5252690315246582,
                1.0673372745513916
              ],
              [
                0.9781750440597534,
                1.7057092189788818,
                1.0242031812667847
              ],
              [
                0.7563002109527588,
                1.8089666366577148,
                0.8255313634872437
              ],
              [
                0.6146100759506226,
                1.9117887020111084,
                0.368009090423584
              ],
              [
                0.5726678371429443,
                1.9956049919128418,
                0.18548542261123657
              ],
              [
                0.4700773060321808,
                2.130831718444824,
                0.022279858589172363
              ],
              [
                0.2809561789035797,
                2.2566030025482178,
                -0.09508982300758362
              ],
              [
                -0.020577847957611084,
                2.3120527267456055,
                -0.14010587334632874
              ],
              [
                -0.3296802341938019,
                2.281888723373413,
                -0.09030210971832275
              ],
              [
                -0.5734552145004272,
                2.1982598304748535,
                0.063102126121521
              ],
              [
                -0.7143107652664185,
                2.0714614391326904,
                0.32609623670578003
              ],
              [
                -0.714654803276062,
                1.9117887020111084,
                0.704669713973999
              ],
              [
                -0.6603711843490601,
                1.6230847835540771,
                1.0399469137191772
              ],
              [
                -0.7036638259887695,
                1.2259819507598877,
                1.1522256135940552
              ],
              [
                -0.8844012022018433,
                0.8598360419273376,
                1.1333403587341309
              ],
              [
                -1.2424516677856445,
                0.6640021800994873,
                1.07512629032135
              ],
              [
                -1.5709213018417358,
                0.710712730884552,
                0.9744400978088379
              ],
              [
                -1.7952327728271484,
                0.9225581288337708,
                0.7847572565078735
              ],
              [
                -1.918294906616211,
                1.2473043203353882,
                0.5570305585861206
              ],
              [
                -1.9430160522460938,
                1.632717251777649,
                0.34221315383911133
              ],
              [
                -1.9179303646087646,
                1.7906527519226074,
                0.2413727045059204
              ],
              [
                -1.8539397716522217,
                1.9498507976531982,
                0.08201402425765991
              ],
              [
                -1.7422277927398682,
                2.074662685394287,
                -0.1307205855846405
              ],
              [
                -1.5739785432815552,
                2.12943959236145,
                -0.39168858528137207
              ],
              [
                -1.4084653854370117,
                2.101039409637451,
                -0.6227225065231323
              ],
              [
                -1.2622238397598267,
                2.018277645111084,
                -0.7576898336410522
              ],
              [
                -1.062330961227417,
                1.9084441661834717,
                -0.8094995021820068
              ],
              [
                -0.7358642816543579,
                1.7988282442092896,
                -0.791060745716095
              ],
              [
                -0.3141660988330841,
                1.636258602142334,
                -0.7310407757759094
              ],
              [
                -0.11715522408485413,
                1.4371027946472168,
                -0.6912686824798584
              ],
              [
                0.0005134642124176025,
                1.210427165031433,
                -0.674283504486084
              ],
              [
                0.18418511748313904,
                0.9652981162071228,
                -0.6826245188713074
              ],
              [
                0.541795551776886,
                0.7710164189338684,
                -0.713899552822113
              ],
              [
                0.8791866898536682,
                0.8175182938575745,
                -0.7456703782081604
              ],
              [
                1.1301640272140503,
                1.0657851696014404,
                -0.7703192234039307
              ],
              [
                1.2285329103469849,
                1.4767986536026,
                -0.7802283763885498
              ],
              [
                1.270639419555664,
                1.7391345500946045,
                -0.7550599575042725
              ],
              [
                1.4038491249084473,
                1.9311418533325195,
                -0.6573927402496338
              ],
              [
                1.638497233390808,
                2.011077642440796,
                -0.45398378372192383
              ],
              [
                1.984919548034668,
                1.9371986389160156,
                -0.11159008741378784
              ],
              [
                2.377054452896118,
                1.6190400123596191,
                0.35915905237197876
              ],
              [
                2.5386343002319336,
                1.1714740991592407,
                0.7284424304962158
              ],
              [
                2.4231719970703125,
                0.7558417916297913,
                0.9701688289642334
              ]
            ],
            "closed": true,
            "curveType": "centripetal",
            "tension": 0.5
          },
          "tubularSegments": 100,
          "radius": 0.05,
          "radialSegments": 8,
          "closed": true
        }
      ],
      "materials": [
        {
          "uuid": "3d2250ef-63cd-4b79-86aa-d1955f893d43",
          "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
          "color": 16777215,
          "envMapRotation": [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            "XYZ"
          ],
          "reflectivity": 1,
          "refractionRatio": 0.98,
          "side": 2,
          "blendColor": 0,
          "wireframe": true
        }
      ],
      "object": {
        "uuid": "82605a97-b90d-4008-87f0-c8fb49fc4fd6",
        "type": "Mesh",
        "layers": 1,
        "matrix": [
          1,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          0,
          1
        ],
        "up": [
          0,
          1,
          0
        ],
        "geometry": "334a7738-6879-4941-9bbf-a7d762a1ae27",
        "material": "3d2250ef-63cd-4b79-86aa-d1955f893d43"
      }
    }
  }

And here is my code for the rails for the railroad:
const extrudedGeometry = useMemo(() => {
    // left half
    const leftHalf = new THREE.Shape();
    leftHalf.moveTo(-.123, -.0135);
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.123, .0135)
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.115, .0135)
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.115, .025)
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.135, .025)
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.135, -.025)
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.115, -.025)
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.115, -.0135)
    leftHalf.lineTo(-.123, -.0135)


    // right half
    const rightHalf = new THREE.Shape();
    rightHalf.moveTo(.123, -.0135);
    rightHalf.lineTo(.123, .0135)
    rightHalf.lineTo(.115, .0135)
    rightHalf.lineTo(.115, .025)
    rightHalf.lineTo(.135, .025)
    rightHalf.lineTo(.135, -.025)
    rightHalf.lineTo(.115, -.025)
    rightHalf.lineTo(.115, -.0135)
    rightHalf.lineTo(.123, -.0135)

    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( [leftHalf, rightHalf], {steps: 300, bevelEnabled: false, extrudePath: props.line})
    return geometry;
  }, [props.line])

  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null} scale={[2,2,2]} position={[-.4, -.5, 0]}>
      <mesh name="Rails" geometry={extrudedGeometry} material={railsMaterial} />
    </group>
  )

I am unsure why it isn't working. If anyone knows what might be happening with this, please let me know. Thank you for your help!
